# Hide sensitive data on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, information-hiding

I am using my react, redux, firebase, Firestore, auth project and uploaded my project on free google Firebase Hosting.

I am newbie
when I goto inspect and check the console and other code.
my code and information still visible to general public like user email and first and last name.
I was thinking npm run build hides everything automatically.

please help me how to hide sensitive data on free Firebase Hosting.

much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you deploy to Firebase Hosting is public.  There is no way to change this behavior.

If you are worried about your Firebase configuration, that must be public, and it is safe as long as you have security rules correctly in place.  See also: [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)

Comment: many Thanks. can you please direct how to hide all sensitive project info using cloud functions or another way. Thanks